# How can parse the url when encountering error "xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag"?

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

I want to extract all links in element `DOCUMENT` in the webpage:

[target to be parsed](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000132680120000013/0001326801-20-000013-index-headers.html)

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000132680120000013/0001326801-20-000013-index-headers.html'
ob=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(ob)
```

It encounters issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1968, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 925, in parseString
    return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
    parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 876, column 23
```

Maybe it is a bad-formated xml file ,how to load it with minidom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what this file is, but it's not XML, and it can't be parsed using an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it is not a xml file,parse it with lxml.html,select all urls with xpath.

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000132680120000013/0001326801-20-000013-index-headers.html'
ob=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(ob)
links = doc.xpath('//pre/a')
for link in links:
    print(link.attrib['href'])
```